# AWS Lambda Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: Syntax error in module 'salesAnalysisReport': invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am working on AWS Solutions Architecting Module 13 Challenge Lab. I have written the following code in my AWS Lambda SalesAnalysisReport function's `salesAnalysisReport.py` file :

```
    response = snsClient.publish(
        TopicArn = arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:507782174659:SalesReportTopic,
        Subject = 'Daily Sales Analysis Report',
        Message = message.getvalue()    
    )
```

I am running default `hello-world` test case and getting the following error message :

```
[ERROR] Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: Syntax error in module 'salesAnalysisReport': invalid syntax (salesAnalysisReport.py, line 129)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/salesAnalysisReport.py" Line 129
TopicArn = arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:507782174659:SalesReportTopic,END RequestId: 5bb30f77-0fae-453a-8f56-b89cdbd064a8
```

I am using `Python 3.8` as directed in lab instructions.

I would like to know the cause of error so that I can resolve it

P.S. - Line 129(error causing line) is

`TopicArn = arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:507782174659:SalesReportTopic,`

I tried putting the value of `TopicArn` in double quotes and then using that for `TopicArn` but that didn't work.

Comment: TopicArn have to be string

Comment: Okay, now after reading your comment I tried with single quotes and now that error is resolve, Thanks :)
Though now I have a new error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose it in single quotes, so it is a `string` as required by Boto3.

Try:

```py
response = snsClient.publish(
        TopicArn = 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:507782174659:SalesReportTopic',
        Subject = 'Daily Sales Analysis Report',
        Message = message.getvalue()    
)
```